# Products on separate lines at woocommerce checkout when quantity is >1

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I am using **woocommerce** subscription with the gifting extension. With this it is possible to gift a subscription to a recipient. I am trying to make it possible to gift a subscription to multiple people in one order.

The tricky thing is that each product by default can only be gifted to 1 person. So in order to gift to multiple people, the same product has to be added to the cart multiple times.

With the use of this thread: [WooCommerce - Treat cart items separate if quantity is more than 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32485152/woocommerce-treat-cart-items-separate-if-quantity-is-more-than-1)

I have managed to add the same product to the cart and show in on multiple lines. So if I enter quantity 5 of my subscription product and add it to the cart I get five entries in my cart. Which is great, as now I can gift every line to another person.

However, when I proceed to checkout it gets messed up again. Instead of showing the product on separate lines, everything get jammed together. Thus on checkout I get to see 1 line with quantity 5, instead of 5 lines with quantity 1.

This is where the question comes in:

**How can I make sure that the order review table on the checkout page shows separate lines for a product with quantity x>1 instead of 1 line with quantity x?**

Remark:
I figured out that it only does not work when the woocommerce subscription gifting add-on is active. It overrides seem to override the wc_cart_item_data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WooCommerce - Treat cart items separate if quantity is more than 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32485152/woocommerce-treat-cart-items-separate-if-quantity-is-more-than-1)

Answer (score 5):

you can use this code

```
    function separate_individual_cart_items( $cart_item_data, $product_id ) {
      $unique_cart_item_key = md5( microtime() . rand() );
      $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = $unique_cart_item_key;

      return $cart_item_data;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'separate_individual_cart_items', 10, 2 );
```

you can put this code into functions.php or into yout own plugin ( a best solution).

And a observation because this question is similar like this question

[WooCommerce - Treat cart items separate if quantity is more than 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32485152/woocommerce-treat-cart-items-separate-if-quantity-is-more-than-1)

but I can't close the question, sorry... my reputation is low)