# Set all items in saperated rows even if product is added twice in WooCommerce cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product-quantity

I tried using [Separated cart items in Woocommerce when quantity is more than 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54054157/separated-cart-items-in-woocommerce-when-quantity-is-more-than-1/54054698#54054698) answer code, but after adding product if I come back to the same product page and add it again, it's not adding to new row But increasing the quantity which I do not want, I want new row as a new item every time.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'mai_split_multiple_quantity_products_to_separate_cart_items', 10, 6 );
function mai_split_multiple_quantity_products_to_separate_cart_items( $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data ) {

    // If product has more than 1 quantity
    if ( $quantity > 1 ) {

        // Keep the product but set its quantity to 1
        WC()->cart->set_quantity( $cart_item_key, 1 );

        // Run a loop 1 less than the total quantity
        for ( $i = 1; $i <= $quantity -1; $i++ ) {
            /**
             * Set a unique key.
             * This is what actually forces the product into its own cart line item
             */
            $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5( microtime() . rand() . "Hi Mom!" );

            // Add the product as a new line item with the same variations that were passed
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, 1, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this issue, use the following code replacement:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'filter_add_cart_item_data' );
function filter_add_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data ) {
    if ( ! isset($cart_item_data['unique_key']) ) {
        $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5(microtime().rand());
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'split_cart_items_by_quantity', 10, 6 );
function split_cart_items_by_quantity( $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data ) {
    if ( $quantity == 1 ) return;
        
    // Keep the product but set its quantity to 1
    WC()->cart->set_quantity($cart_item_key, 1);

    // Loop through each unit of item quantity
    for ( $i = 1; $i <= $quantity -1; $i++ ) {
        // Make each quantity item unique and separated
        $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5(microtime().rand());

        // Add each item quantity as a separated cart item
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, 1, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Comment: it worked, thank so  much